# Use promise-returning code without async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to quickly write a simple tool in NodeJS using [pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib). pdf-lib appears to be designed to use promises and async/await, but I don't want the extra code complexity of async/await for such a simple tool.

How can I use functions that return a promise without the extra bother of async/await?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the library primarily uses Promises, you *will* have to learn how to use Promises regardless, if you want to be able to use the library.

If you think `async`/`await` will be too difficult, you can construct `.then` chains instead. When you start with a Promise or have a Promise inside a `.then`, make another `.then`, whose callback will run when the Promise resolves. For example, this:

```
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes)

// Embed the Helvetica font
const helveticaFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.Helvetica)
```

if you want to do away with `async`/`await`, can be

```
// first Promise
PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes)
  .then((pdfDoc) => {
    // second Promise: return it so its resolve value can be used in the next `.then`
    return pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.Helvetica);
  })
  .then((helveticaFont) => {
    // helveticaFont is now available inside this `.then`
  })
  .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this
```

Or you could nest the second `.then` inside to have access both to `pdfDoc` and `helveticaFont` at once, or use `Promise.all`:

```
PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes)
  .then((pdfDoc) => {
    return pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.Helvetica)
      .then((helveticaFont) => {
        // both helveticaFont and are available inside this `.then`
      });
   })
  .catch(handleErrors);
```

or

```
const pdfDoc = await 
// first Promise
PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes)
  .then((pdfDoc) => {
    return Promise.all([pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.Helvetica), pdfDoc]);
  })
  .then(([helveticaFont, pdfDoc]) => {
    // both helveticaFont and are available inside this `.then`
   })
  .catch(handleErrors);
```

But, as you can see, it gets really messy when you have lots of asynchronous requests to make. I'd highly recommend using `async`/`await` here if at all possible - it'll make things much easier and much less complicated. On the contrary, deliberately avoiding `async`/`await` will probably make things significantly (and unnecessarily) more tedious.

Comment: Ok thanks. It's not even about understanding the concept of async/await. I already know roughly how they work. It just pisses me off that the general obsession with async JS wastes forces me to turn an extremely simple and straightfoward tool into a mess of multiple functions and trying to make sure everything happens in the right order. Synchronous programming is so much _easier!_ I was just really hoping there was some magic way to say to the promise "just be like a normal function and _block_ and don't try to be asynchronous". I honestly don't know how you write clean code with async/await.

Comment: The point of async/await is to write clean code. Could you please give me an example where you found async/await with messy code?

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes [For instance](https://jsfiddle.net/v6ce0kgw/). I don't know how I'm supposed to make that work without making the code disgusting. I don't know what to do when every second function in the library returns a function. I'm sure there's a simple solution but you can imagine how frustrating it is when I just wanted to do a 20 minute job and now it's taking over an hour because I have to go and learn how async/await works, and not only learn how it works, but also what programming patterns you're supposed to use with it. Nothing's ever simple :|

Comment: @Clonkex See their demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Hopding/rxwsc8f5/13/ That code looks pretty reasonable to me. The alternative of using `.then`s instead would be way uglier IMO.